# boton que envia a otra pagina en html

Tags: html, css, web, botón

estoy creando un formulario de registro y tengo un pequeño problema.
tengo un boton y cuando doy clic no hace nada ni me lleva a ninguna pagina

```
    <body>

    <div class="login-page">
      <div class="form">
        <img src="imagenes/valetparking.jpg" height="100px" alt="">
        <h1>Bienvenidos</h1>

  <form class="login-form">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Ingresa tu correo electronico"/>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Número de celular"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre completo"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Apellidos"/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña"/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="confirmar contraseña"/>
    <button onclick="location.href=index.html" >Registrarse </button>

    <p class="message">Ya tienes una cuenta? <a href="login.html">Inicia sesión</a></p>
  </form>
</div>
</div>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en verdad te estas planteando mal el formulario,y como envias datos desde un form,

deberias colocar esto

```
 <form class="login-form"  action="miurl" method="post">
```

y luego cambiar el button por esto

```
 <button type="submit" >Registrarse </button>
```

asi es la forma tipica de enviar datos que estan dentro de un "form" en html

El "button" hace referencia a un botón genérico, y los "submit" són un tipo de botones preparados para enviar información de formularios, es decir, permiten recoger la información de los "input" que haya dento del "form", empaquetarlos y luego enviar estos datos a la url que hayas colocado en el "action" de la etiqueta "form"

Comment: hola gracias por el comentario. si me sirvió mucho tu ayuda. tengo la ultima duda referente a esto. osea si yo envio los datos a una base de datos y al mismo tiempo que se redirija a la pagina de inicio como debería hacerlo?

Comment: podrias hacerlo desde el backend, o desde el frontend si lo envias dinamicamente al enviar el post, desde ahi, solo tendras que redireccionar una vez salvas el resultado.
Podrias ponerlo en el button, de esta manera aunque no lo recomiendo, <input onclick="window.location.href = 'https://website.com/my-account';" type="submit" value="Submit request" />

Comment: eso ya seria otra pregunta con una larga explicacion , pero la manera sencilla es enviar los datos del form a una pagina php y que esta pagina se encargue de guardarlo en la base de datos